# Converting Multiline cell data into Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to convert the multiline text data in cell to individual rows. Also, there's more information corresponding to the cell data in similar format so I need the new row to take that into consideration as well.

Current shape of Data:

[image: Current shape of data]

Expected shape of Data:

[image: Expected shape of data]

I read the instructions to ensure the text in images is available as text within the question body, since the text is significant, I am working on converting into a table and will edit this question with it once done.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Edited the question. The question is that I am at loss how to do this.
Had it been only once column with multiline text needing splitting into individual rows, I could have used Power Query. Unfortunately, if I follow the same method, it'd generate a lot of incorrect data for me and having to clean it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in PowerQuery.

Move id and total to the left, select id and total, then use Transform>Unpivot Other Columns to get this:

[image]

Select the Value column, right click and use Split Column by Delimeter, configured like this:

[image]

You now have this:

[image]

Select id, total and Attribute, then use Transform>Unpivot Other Columns. You should now have this:

[image]

Select Attribute and use Transform>Pivot column, configured like this:

[image]

You should now have this:

[image]

Remove/rename/reposition columns as appropriate, then use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook. I have renamed and changed the Attribute.1 column to show an index within each group (could be useful later!):

[image]

My source data is in a table called Table1. Here's the full text from the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", type text}, {"quantity", type text}, {"total", type number}, {"item price", type text}, {"article number", type text}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type",{"id", "total", "quantity", "item price", "article number"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Reordered Columns", {"id", "total"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2", "Value.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Value.1", type number}, {"Value.2", type number}, {"Value.3", type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"id", "total", "Attribute"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Attribute.1", "index_in_id"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns","Value.","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"index_in_id"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"index_in_id", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```